# How to show unique strings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to categorise Companies by letters in my listing page. 
But there are multiple records that start with the same letter. I can get the first letters of Company names with the `.first` method.

But my code shows duplicate letters.

Controller:

```
 @brand = Brand.where(slug: params[:brand]).first
 @companies = Company.where(brand_id: @brand.id)....
```

View:

```
 <% @companies.each do |c| %>
       <li>
         <%= link_to company_path(c.brand.name,c.id) do  %>
            <%= c.name.first %>
         <% end  %>
       </li>
   <% end %>
```

How would I show only unique letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New code (with some changes, assuming company belongs_to brand and brand has_many companies)

```
@brand = Brand.where(slug: params[:brand]).first
@companies = @brand.companies
#@list is a hash with letters as keys and an array of companies starting with this letter
@list = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] } 
@companies.each { |comp| @list[comp.name[0]] << comp }

#As “engineersmnky” suggested on a comment the last two sentences can be simplified:
@list = @companies.group_by { |c| c.name[0] }
```

View:

```
<% @list.each do |letter, companies| %>
  <h2><%= letter %><h2>
  <% companies.each do |c| %>     
    <li>
      <%= link_to c.name, c %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `@list = @companies.group_by {|c| c.name[0]}` is a bit cleaner in my opinion and provides the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through all companies so if you have companies like, `Facebook` and `Foxtel`, a link with `F` tag is going to be duplicated. You can do something like

```
categories = @companies.where(brand_id: @brand.id).pluck(:name).map(&:first).uniq
```

In the above code all it is doing is getting a list of company names and extracting out the first letter and removing the duplicates.

Now you can iterate through the categories and create a link for the category and inside the category page you can get companies starting from that letter

```
Company.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{starting_character}%")
```

`starting_character` gets sent from the list of categories page.

Comment: but with this code i can't get my associated table to link : `<%= link_to company_path(c.brand.name,c.id) do  %>` here  `c.brand.name `

Comment: @YalınSemer You need to do that inside the each categories page, you can do iterate the results you get from `Company.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{starting_character}%")` and do `@companies.each do ... link_to company_path(company.id)`